# Is Adafruit Arduino Feather M0 WiFi compatible with Adafruit Music Maker shield?

Tags: wifi, shields, hardware, adafruit, audio

I want Arduino to receive MP3 by WiFi (from iPhone), and then send to Music Maker codec and amplifier.

I want to use Arduino IDE and library software from Adafruit for the Music Maker, so I need an Arduino board 100% compatible with the library for Music Maker.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Adafruit or at least adding links to the product descriptions, circuits, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not.  Adafruit Feather boards are only compatible with Feather 'wings' and not Arduino shields.